# Outer margins = grid gutter in Neat

Tags: css, sass, neat

This was asked years ago on the Neat github. The user there describes the issue very comprehensively, with images: https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/99

Essentially, I like grid systems, but I don't want elements to touch the edge of the screen. I can easily add padding, and easily retrieve the gutter variable, but not get outside padding that matches the gutter between elements (because gutters are relative to the parent).

A commenter on github mentioned that it was the same as $grid-padding in Susy.

The closing comment on the issue suggested it would be **easy** to implement but never suggested how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is being included in Neat 2.0.0, which is currently in Beta - more information on that here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/485

You can find the code here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/tree/neat-2.0.0

And the top example here looks like what you are trying to achieve:

http://neat.netlify.com/examples/

Hope this helps